# Gin GORM update association by ids

Tags: go, go-gorm, go-gin

I'm using Gin and GORM to make REST API. This is two simple models

```
type User struct {
    gorm.Model
    Email  String
    Topics []*Topic `gorm:"many2many:user_topics" json:"topics"`
}

type Topic struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name  String
    Users []*User `gorm:"many2many:user_topics" json:"users"`
}
```

This is my API update user

```
type UpdateUserParams struct {
    Email    string `json:"email"`
    Topics   []uint `json:"topics"`
}

func UpdateUser(ctx *gin.Context) {
   var userParams UpdateUserParams

   currentUser := ctx.MustGet("currentUser").(User)

   if err := ctx.ShouldBindJSON(&userParams); err != nil {
      // Show error
   }

   result := db.Save(&user)
}
```

When i call API POST /api/auth/update with json data

```
{
    "email": "abc@test",
    "topics": [1, 2, 3]
}
```

it has an error:
`reflect.Set: value of type uint is not assignable to type *Topic`

I want when I call API with that params, it can save Topic data with ID equals 1 and 2 for that user. How can I do that? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

since your input for the topics are a list of ints, you need to first find the corresponding topics with the ids, then use a struct of those topics to update the user.

```
func (db *gorm.DB) UpdateUser(ctx *gin.Context, req *UpdateUserParams) {

   currentUser := ctx.MustGet("currentUser").(User)

   if err := ctx.ShouldBindJSON(&userParams); err != nil {
      // Show error
   }

   var topics []Topic
   db.Find(&topics, req.topics)


   result := db.Save(&User{Name: currentUser.Name, Topics: topics})
}
```